# ZipOutputStream generate corrupted zip file

Tags: java, compression

I use the code below to generate the zip file and return it to the frontend, The performance is normal when the file is small. However, when the compressed file exceeds 1GB, the downloaded file will be conrrupted, and the number of compressed files is reduced, and this phenomenon does not always occur, sometimes downloading 3.2GB files is normal again =_=

Looking forward to hearing from everyone

```
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOutStream = null;
        FileInputStream filenputStream = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            zipOutStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream));
            zipOutStream.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                File file = files.get(i);
                filenputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(filenputStream);
                zipOutStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName[i]));
                int len = 0;
                byte[] bs = new byte[40];
                while ((len = bis.read(bs)) != -1) {
                    zipOutStream.write(bs,0,len);
                }
                bis.close();
                filenputStream.close();
                zipOutStream.closeEntry();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  finally {
            try {
                if(Objects.nonNull(filenputStream)) {
                    filenputStream.close();
                }
                if(Objects.nonNull(bis)) {
                    bis.close();
                }
                if (Objects.nonNull(zipOutStream)) {
                    zipOutStream.flush();
                    zipOutStream.close();
                }
                if (Objects.nonNull(outputStream)) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have set the request header. `response.reset();
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;fileName*=UTF-8''"+ downloadName);`

Comment: With you saying that the zip file is becoming corrupt, and then looking at your finally, you have potential issues with how you are closing your resources, which could lead to corruption of your output file.  If there is an exception thrown when you are trying to close the fileinputstream, none of the other resources will be flushed, or closed. Hence corruption will happen.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at rewriting that code using try-with-resources.  That will shift the management of flushing and closing your resources from your code, to java itself, which will always properly close those resources even with failures.

Comment: As far as why there are failures happening, it could be related to firewall timeouts on your servers that are terminating the connections before the transaction has completed.  I don't know what your environment is like, but we've had many issues with firewalls when dealing with multi-gigabyte streams, and they tend to be intermittent and difficult to reproduce.  My point here, is that the interruption to your stream may not be in your code.

Comment: I totally missed a major memory leak in your code with how you're using the FileInputStream and the BufferedInputStream.... those are never being flushed and closed within that for loop... that's where your corruption is happening... the buffers are not being flushed properly.

Comment: If you like, I can rewrite your code using try with resources, which will fix that memory leak.

Comment: If you can, please give a sample code to see, thank you very much

Comment: When writing the code below, I realized that what I called a "major memory leak" would only be one if there was an exception thrown while processing.  There could have been some other possible leaks, or issues, but I did not fully absorb all of the closes.  But what makes manual closes so difficult is that you have to have catches on every one, so if there is an exception thrown on one, the others still close properly.  Hence why try-with-resources simplifies so much.

Comment: 40 is far too small for an I/O buffer. Use 4096 or 8192.

Answer (score 0):

One of the potential issues with your code is with memory leaks and streams that are not properly flushed and closed if the code runs in to any exceptions.

One way to help reduce these leaks and to ensure all resources are properly closed, even when exceptions occur, is to use try-with-resources.

Here is an example of how your code example can be rewritten to utilize try-with-resources.

In this example, to get it to compile in a detached IDE environment, I've put it in a function named `testStream` since I do not have knowledge as to what contributes to the source of the parameters `files` and `fileName`.  Therefore, validation and content of these two parameters are left to chance, and it is assumed both have the same number of entries, and are paired with each other (element 0 of each are paired together).  Since this odd relationship exists, it's linked by the variable named `i` to mirror the original source code.

```java
    public void testStream( HttpServletResponse response, List<File> files, String[] fileName )
    {
        int i = 0;

        try ( 
                ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                ZipOutputStream zipOutStream = new ZipOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream( outputStream ) ); 
                ) 
        {
            zipOutStream.setMethod( ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED );
            
            for ( File file : files )
            {
                try (
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                                 new FileInputStream( file ) );
                        ) {
                    zipOutStream.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( fileName[i++] ) );
                    int len = 0;
                    byte[] bs = new byte[4096];
                    while ( (len = bis.read( bs )) != -1 )
                    {
                        zipOutStream.write( bs, 0, len );
                    }

                    // optional since putNextEntry will auto-close open entries:
                    zipOutStream.closeEntry();
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This compiles successfully and should work; but may need some other adjustments to get it to work in your environment with your data. Hopefully it eliminates issues you may have been having with closing streams and other resources.

Comment: Resources, such as streams, that implement Closable, can all be used with try-with-resources.  If in doubt, just try to set them up in a try statement, and if it does not implement Closable then it will be indicated as a compile error within your IDE.

Comment: I also almost used `file.getName()` instead of `fileName[i++]` but then I decided against using that since the ZipEntry name may not be the same as the file name.  If they are the same, then making that change will eliminate one of the parameters and also simplify the code that is needed to feed in to this function.